# Is it possible to generate a projection matrix from Quadratic Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

Is it possible to generate a projection matrix from Quadratic Discriminant Analysis, as Linear Discriminant Analysis does?

I have found a library called [mataveid](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid) that can do Linear Discriminant Analysis (and much more) and I notice that at the end of the code, the projection matrix `W` is multiplied with the data `X` and generates a projection called `P`. Is it possible that Quadratic Discriminant Analysis can do the same?

```
function [P,W] = lda(varargin)
  % Check if there is any input
  if(isempty(varargin))
    error('Missing inputs')
  end

  % Get impulse response
  if(length(varargin) >= 1)
    X = varargin{1};
  else
    error('Missing data X')
  end

  % Get the sample time
  if(length(varargin) >= 2)
    y = varargin{2};
  else
    error('Missing class ID y');
  end

  % Get the sample time
  if(length(varargin) >= 3)
    c = varargin{3};
  else
    error('Missing amount of components');
  end

  % Get size of X
  [row, column] = size(X);

  % Create average vector mu_X = mean(X, 2)
    mu_X = mean(X, 2);

    % Count classes
    amount_of_classes = y(end) + 1;

    % Create scatter matrices Sw and Sb
    Sw = zeros(row, row);
    Sb = zeros(row, row);

    % How many samples of each class
    samples_of_each_class = zeros(1, amount_of_classes);
    for i = 1:column
      samples_of_each_class(y(i) + 1) = samples_of_each_class(y(i) + 1) + 1; % Remove +1 if you are using C
    end

    % Iterate all classes
    shift = 1;
    for i = 1:amount_of_classes
      % Get samples of each class
      samples_of_class = samples_of_each_class(i);

      % Copy a class to Xi from X
      Xi = X(:, shift:shift+samples_of_class - 1);

      % Shift
      shift = shift + samples_of_class;

      % Get average of Xi
      mu_Xi = mean(Xi, 2);

      % Center Xi
      Xi = Xi - mu_Xi;

      % Copy Xi and transpose Xi to XiT and turn XiT into transpose
      XiT = Xi';

      % Create XiXiT = Xi*Xi'
      XiXiT = Xi*XiT;

      % Add to Sw scatter matrix
      Sw = Sw + XiXiT;

      % Calculate difference
      diff = mu_Xi - mu_X;

      % Borrow this matrix and do XiXiT = diff*diff'
      XiXiT = diff*diff';

      % Add to Sb scatter matrix - Important to multiply XiXiT with samples of class
      Sb = Sb + XiXiT*samples_of_class;
    end

    % Find the eigenvectors - by solving the generalized eigenvalue problem: Sb*v = Sw*v*lambda
    L = chol(Sw, 'lower');
    Y = linsolve(L, Sb);
    Z = Y*inv(L');
    [V, D] = eig(Z);

    % Sort eigenvectors descending by eigenvalue
    [D, idx] = sort(diag(D), 1, 'descend');
    V = V(:,idx);

    % Get components W
    W = V(:, 1:c);
  P = W'*X;
end
```